# JDBC Template query and spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

I am trying to select the database to get the data from a String:

```
final String queryPorLogin = "SELECT * from usuarios where login=? ";
@Autowired
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

@Override
public boolean validar(String login) {
    return this.jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(queryPorLogin, new Usuarios(), 
    login);
}
```

but I have this error:

[image: error img]

I believe it is not the correct query to use in this case because I want to make a selection on the database and if there is a result use the resultset to do a check (passwords with bcrpyt). Could someone help me?

I need to take the result of this select and make a comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mixed the inputs of the `jdbcTemplate.queryForObject` a bit. It should be:

```
Usuarios usuarios = this.jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(queryPorLogin, 
        new Object[]{login}, 
        Usuarios.class); // can pass also a RowMapper<Usuarios> for more detailed approach
```

The second param takes the list of parameters to bind and the third one take in the `Class` that is expected as a result.

Comment: Thanks with this user can I make comparisons is there any way to use resultset?

Comment: Yes you need to pass in as the 3rd param a RowMapper<Usuarios>. It should contain impelementation of the mappings

Comment: Even though it's only 1 record of this table?

Comment: That is the old API. You don't need an `Object[]` the newer api has varargs and those need to be the last argument.

Comment: Its not deprecated in the current version

Comment: I am using the most current version I tried to do this with documents data acess with jdbc

Comment: Usuarios usuarios = this.jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(queryPorLogin, 
                new Object[]{login}, 
                new RowMapper<Usuarios>() {
                    public Usuarios mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                     Usuarios actor = new Usuarios();
                     if(BCrypt.checkpw(senha, rs.getString("senha")))) {
                      return true;
                     }
                        return usuarios;
                    }
                    });

Comment: I would need to do something like this with rs.getString ("password") do a verification with the jtextfield password 
could you give me an example of what it would look like in the new api?

Comment: It isn't deprecated but that doesn't mean the code sample is wrong (although judging by the error he is using a non-varargs version of Spring so an old one which doesn't have this yet).

Comment: You should verify before passing anything to front end in my opinion

Comment: yes but bcrpyt needs database password to verify, thanks bro

Answer (score 1):

To me it looks like `queryForMap` seems to be a better option for your case.

`Map<String, Object> map = jdbcTemplate.queryForMap(sql, login);`

Which will result in a single row mapped with key as String and value as object.  You can then check your bcrypt.

And if your preference is `queryForObject` you already have an answer above.

[Example](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?class=org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate&method=queryForMap)

Comment: After that I need a for each to get the password and login?

Comment: or use contains?

Comment: If your table contains single row per login, `queryForMap` is better suited and you don't need a loop.  Otherwise `queryForList` and a loop is required.  See edit for example.

Comment: contains single row 
and then I have to use contains to check if the bd password is the same as the one entered?

Comment: Possibly equals and not just contains. But as you said you may need to bcrypt it before comparison.

Comment: yes yes i will encrypt the password string before and after using equals or contains thanks man